# how ref only article of 2012 in my bib file

Tags: biblatex

My question is :
How can I print only article of 2012 from my bib file?

For more clear, consider command `\printbibliography[type=article]`.
This command only print article of .bib file.
I want print only article with year=2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is more than unclear and the tags are incompatible with one another.

Comment: Are you looking to print all bib entries with 2012 in the year (or date) field, or only the entries of type `@article` that were published in 2012? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico, only entries of type \@article, published in 2012.

Comment: Do [Specify different date ranges for \printbibliography in biblatex with biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373750/35864), [biblatex, biber, is it possible to \printbibliography between two years?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346270/35864), [Date format (in bib entry) / bibelatex biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350697/35864) give you enough hints or do you need more help? If you need more help an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have so far can help us get started more quickly.